# What is the simplest version of best practice application architecture for a backend in C# and ASP.NET Core WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-web-api, clean-architecture, onion-architecture

I know that in some contexts, best practice would be DDD, CQRS and EventSourcing, but in my case this would be too complicated of two reasons:

- My team is beginners, and we want them to be productive as early as possible
- The application is really simple, but obviously the complexity may grow in time

This question is an attempt at rephrasing this question: [What is a simple implementation of onion architecture for C# ASP.NET Core WebAPI and SQL db that is not full DDD and CQRS?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/405686/what-is-a-simple-implementation-of-onion-architecture-for-c-asp-net-core-webapihttps://)

My thoughts so far are:

- using onion or clean architecture is better than the old n-tier model, and no harder to learn, and it makes it easier to unit test the domain entity layer
- The API should not return data as objects of the domain entities, but it should be mapped to separate view models

I am not sure of whether to design the database and SQLs manually, and then use Dapper - or go for something like EntityFramework Core - code first.

I wonder if CQRS would be a good idea, even without DDD.

I would also like to say a little bit about our simple application. It is for an amusement park where seasonal employees in different departments are required to take some training courses. They should be able to register for a course, cancel their registration, and the responsible trainer for the course should be able to mark registration with attendance and approvement. Also there is some reporting, which is all reading and showing these data. This is version 1.

Version 2 is admin dashboard for registering users as trainers and admins (which can see all the reports). Admins should also be able to map which departments require which training courses.

Maybe many will see this as opinion based, but I believe that it should be possible to define some broad steps in a learning ladder about application architecture, and even though the exact sequence may be debatable, I expect some kind of consensus about which steps should be considered. So that is my question; above simple layering, n-tier and onion/clean - and below CQRS, DDD EventSourcing, what concrete topics/learning steps exist in application architecture in this context?

Comment: In most cases; simplicity (for juniors) and flexibility (for growing complexity) are orthogonal concepts. If the simple junior solution were the flexible one, we wouldn't need such a vast array of advanced design patterns and architectures. Any early step you simplify tends to end up as technical debt for later. So we can't really build you a narrow ladder when the top end of the ladder will widen whenever the bottom end gets narrowed. I suggest first deciding on where to land on the junior-friendly vs clean-code balance before continuing to analyze.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that the ladder widens, but I am being quite specific about where my ladder goes (DDD, CQRS), so it should be possible to suggest what the intermediate steps are. Because that is what I am asking.

Comment: The simplest version of best practice architecture for an ASP.NET MVC application is the one that comes with it: MVC.

Comment: `I am not sure of whether to design the database and SQLs manually, and then use Dapper - or go for something like EntityFramework Core - code first.` -- It doesn't matter.  Do what makes the most sense for your class and your students.  Do what best serves your teaching purposes.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, **there is no such thing as a "best practice" architecture.**  There is only that architecture that best fits the specific need at hand.

We're doing a great disservice to software developers new to our industry by continuing to teach a vocabulary-based, syntax-based "pattern-based, best-practice" style of development without explaining *why* all of these patterns exist in the first place.

Software patterns are tried-and-true solutions to certain specific problems in software development, not a cornucopia of options from which one can stitch together a solution like a quilt.  We need software developers who can think for themselves and solve problems, not mindlessly follow some all-encompassing "standard" for application development.

So what should we be teaching in the way of software architecture?  **Principles first.** 
Wikipedia lists several [software design considerations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design#Design_considerations), and certainly a good software architecture touches all of these principles, but the most important of these principles is **modularity.** Modularily achieves all of the others.

Everyone that's been in our industry for a non-trivial amount of time knows what a "Big Ball of Mud" is, and how easy it is to create one.  The solution to the Big Ball of Mud is not to create a five-tier architecture with DDD, BDD, TDD, CQRS, and however many other acronyms you can think of thrown into the salad bowl for good luck.  The solution is, in fact, absurdly simple: **push as much functionality away from the UI as possible**, and let the UI be responsible solely for interacting with the user.

That's it.

So teach the techniques.  Show your students CQRS.  Help them understand MVC.  Show them how to create a class design that is SOLID.  But make sure your students understand *why* they are doing these things, and that **the "why" comes first.**

Understand first what you need your architecture to accomplish, and you will then be in the best position to choose the techniques that most effectively meet those needs.

Comment: And to this *very* excellent post I would add just one more thought:  "there's really no such thing as 'MVC.'"  No, not exactly.  Like every other model or pattern that we might use to describe the general structure of a [large] application, it's only a general description useful for conversation.  Patterns are useful for discussion and description but they're not a box of prefabricated parts and no actual application conforms to any of them exactly.  But you can certainly see where a designer "tried too hard" and made things much worse. ***Clarity*** **is key.**

Comment: I almost wish we had a bot that would take any question that contains "best practice" in the title and auto-comment with a link to [the meta question about best practices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/).